# Knowledge graph/table for web developer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen general chart for programmer level (knowledge of paterns\oop\langagues\testing etc.)

Is there any good chart to evaluate your knowledge of web development(CSS\HTML\JavaScript\SVG\client-server communication)?

Comment: I don't think that this is a suitable question for stackoverflow.

Comment: This would probably be more suitable on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Out of curiosity, which general programmer charts are you refering to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

http://smarterer.com/

It's a free skills Benchmark. You will find several quiz like CSS/HTML/SQL/ASP/jQuery/Javascript...

Pros : Questions are created by website users :)

Comment: There are similar non-user-created tests on sites like oDesk and Freelancer.com.